# removing entirely NA rows in excel files with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, row

I am making excel file merging program, and I found there are so many blank rows in excel file. I try to erase it but it does not works. This is my codding as followed.

```
def btncmd():

    total_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in file_content:
        df = pd.read_excel(i)
        total_df = total_df.append(df, ignore_index = True)
```

file_content is a list that has excel files. I will also attach the image of excel file samples.
[image]

```
        total_df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
    total_df
```

I found there are so many blank in excel file. excel rows[2:3] is okay but the other blank rows need to remove.  I want to remove the blank rows so I used dropna(how = 'all'), but it does not works in my codding.

```
    merged_excel_file = "D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서/"+ txt_file.get()  + ".xlsx"

    total_df.to_excel(merged_excel_file, sheet_name = "sheet", index=False)

    print('생성파일:', merged_excel_file)
```

I changed csv file into xlsx file and saved it. I works well. but the excel file title is repeated and it should be removed except the first one. I checked it in the image of excel file

```
btn = Button(frame_folder, text='클릭', command=btncmd)
btn.pack(side='left', padx=6, pady=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just drop rows with NaN values after doing doing

```
df = pd.read_excel(i)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

That should remove any row which contains a nan value. If you used how=all then it will only remove a row where all the values are nan, i.e. a row with 9 values and one column that contains something will not be removed.

You also need to include inplace=True so that it modifies the dataframe. If you don't do this it won't modify the dataframe but will instead return a dataframe with nan values removed.

Comment: I changed the code but it is not what I want to do. It erases all rows. I want to remove row 6th, 17th, 18th, 26th, 27th. The output of file_content will be changed everytime, so remove rows will be changed.

Comment: OK. I guess that you have a Nan value in every row so it removes all of the rows. In that case I think you need to add a threshold value - try df.dropna(inplace=True, thresh=2) for instance. Play around with that until it just removes those rows you're interested in. Hope that helps.